# Howto write DDL ALTER TABLE Modify statement using string variable for TABLE name

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ddl

In a loop I want to change for some fields the Type and Length programmatically.
With the DDL Statement ALTER Table Alter Column I was successful, 
but only with the hardcoded table name. For the Field Name I could use
the a string variable.
As I wrote the table name   TDF.Name, which was the product 
of a "For each TDF" statement, and running this code:

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
For Each TDF In dbs.TableDefs 
strfield = "M1"
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE TDF.Name ALTER COLUMN strField TEXT(5);"
DBEngine(0)(0).Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

an error  occured. "TDF.MDB" could not be found.
Please can somebody tell me the right Syntax for the
variables for the target database and table
table  e.g. -> "databasename.MDB / tablename" ?

Many thanks in advance
Helmut Steinecker

Answer (score 2):

The db engine doesn't know anything about `TDF.Name` and `strField`, so include their values in your DDL statement ...

```vb
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE [" & TDF.Name & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & strField & "] TEXT(5);"
```

Beware `For Each TDF In dbs.TableDefs` means the code will attempt to execute an `ALTER TABLE` against every table in the database, including system tables such as `MSysObjects`.  I suggest you should not attempt to alter system tables ...

```vb
For Each TDF In dbs.TableDefs
    If Not (TDF.Name Like "MSys*") Then
        ' ALTER TABLE
    End If
Next
```

Comment: re Not altering system tables: cue [Queen - The prophet's song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZjjsrn9FY4) . (Sorry for off-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks, HansUp,
Since I have read so many answers of yours,
I was hoping, you will answer and so:
You gave me the solution.
May I append a database Name to the table variable?
Since I had 255 fields, I got the famous - too many fields error message.
I will reduce the fields, and then, slowly, increase by
adding fields. With 600 tables, this will be another DDL statement. 
but now I am on the way to success.
Many thanks from Bavaria, Ottobrunn, south of Munich.

Comment: Hello, Helmut.  Access will not allow you to qualify the table name with the database or schema name in a SQL statement as you might expect from experience with other databases.  You could connect to a remote Access db and execute the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the number of fields, mostly MEMO fields - for me, better than Text fields, for my purposes, did work. Now I have 6xLongInteger, 1xText, 241xMEMO fields and now I get no more the "Too Many Fields" message.